# How to add certificate to 'www' subdomain in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, dns, ssl-certificate

The Azure Portal has changed how they issue certificates. I have not been able to figure out how to secure the www of my app service domain name. I was able to apply a new cert to the root domain jasonrsmithmusic.com but not [www.jasonrsmithmusic.com](http://www.jasonrsmithmusic.com) with the following error:

> Error adding managed certificate: Properties.CanonicalName is invalid.
> Current CNAME records of the hostname [www.jasonrsmithmusic.com](http://www.jasonrsmithmusic.com) is
> jasonrsmithmusic.com

[image: Azure Portal Error]
[image: GoDaddy DNS]

=======================================
Update: Made progress based on an answer below but the cert is still listed as invalid.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment added www.subdomain successfully.***

***Note***: To map a subdomain `www.jasonrsmithmusic.com` ensure you should use A record instead of CNAME record like below.

[image]

To resolve this issue, you need to add a new custom domain name along with `www.jasonrsmithmusic.com`  I have one previous custom domain name as `travwebapp.com`  I use this custom domain as `www.travwebapp.com` like below.

And added a service managed certificate.

[image]

[image]

To know more in detail please check this reference

[Map existing custom DNS name - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=a%2Cazurecli)

[Add and manage TLS/SSL certificates - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal)

Comment: I was able to make progress but the cert is still flagged as invalid. I added screenshots to the original post to add clarity.

Comment: Please check this [reference](https://www.eugenechiang.com/2019/02/24/adding-ssl-certificate-to-get-rid-of-the-not-secure-message-to-your-web-app/) is useful

Comment: If I must go buy a cert from somewhere else then why did I add the one from Azure?

Comment: Ok got it sorted. I just bought one through the azure portal and applied it in the same way I applied the free ones. But now the 'unsecure' error is gone. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I had my 'www' subdomain set up as an A record in the way you are describing and still received the error.